# Website hacked and suspended for spam, effect on SEO

Tags: seo, spam

I had my website on first 5 positions on google for 3 main keywords.
Because of some poorly written forms my website was suspended by my host because of SPAM for 3 days.

Now the position of my website is 40-50.

Can I ever get back my lost positions?
Or google "blacklisted" my domain for spam?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not much I can tell about your particular scenario, however, I can say this.

Google does check black lists and Google does get nervous if your site disappears for a period. Check http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx to see if your domain name and/or IP address is blacklisted anywhere. Remove from any blacklists the best you can and wait.

Fortunately, Google is rather forgiving. Some blacklists are not much of a concern to Google but an indication of something wrong.

Still it will take a quite a while for your domain name to rebuild trust. Time and consistency are the only cures. Once Google sees that the issues are over, your trust score will begin to rise again and your placement in the SERPs should return. But you will have to be very patient. It will pay off in the end.

Answer (score 2):

You will regain your position with time. Be patient. Google is playing it safe right now. Once they see that the spam is gone, and your site is back up, running normally, you will gain your positions back.

Also, no need to worry about the blacklist. That is for multiple repeat offenders.

Comment: Thanks! I see that I was blacklisted by Spamhaus ZEN. I'll try to de-blacklist it.